# Sockets BeginReceive issue

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

Why am I getting an error of [BeginReceive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxkwh6zw.aspx) method of Size (3rd parameter)?

But BUFFER_SIZE its never bigger (in lenght) then the constant value (its 2048 bytes).

This is my code:

```
public void Send(byte[] byteData, M.StateObject _stateObj, Socket client)
    {
        // Begin sending the data to the remote client(s):
        client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendData), _stateObj);
    }

    void SendData(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            M.StateObject stateObj = (M.StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = stateObj.server;
            byte[] data = stateObj.data;
            int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
            client.BeginReceive(data, 0, M.StateObject.BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData), stateObj);
            allDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnMessageShowing(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void ClientLogging(object _data, M.StateObject _stateObj)
    {
        M.UserData client = _data as M.UserData;
        if (client != null)
        {
            //setting properties:
            client.bConnectred = true;

            // 1. add client to list of clients:
            ClientAddingRemoving(_stateObj, client, true);

            // 2. showing welcome on server
            OnMessageShowing(client.ServerNotifying());

            // 3. refreshing the list of clients on server`s main form
            OnClientsListRefreshing(bll.ClientsListCreating(listOfClients));

            // 4. send welcome note to all clients:
            byte[] bytesToSend = M.SerializeServer.Login_WelcomeToAllClients(client);
            bytesToSend = M.BytesArrayGetSet.BytesSending_Set(bytesToSend);
            SendToAll(bytesToSend, _stateObj.server);

            // 5. send list of all users to logged client:
            bytesToSend = M.SerializeServer.Login_ToLoggedClient(bll.ListOfAllUsers(listOfClients));
            bytesToSend = M.BytesArrayGetSet.BytesSending_Set(bytesToSend);
            Send(bytesToSend, _stateObj, _stateObj.server);

            //6. send new client to list of all other clients:
            bytesToSend = M.SerializeServer.Login_ToAllClients(client);
            bytesToSend = M.BytesArrayGetSet.BytesSending_Set(bytesToSend);
            SendToAll(bytesToSend, _stateObj.server);
        }
    }

    private void SendToAll(byte[] data, Socket _socket)
    {
        foreach (M.StateObject stObj in listOfClients.Keys) //dictionary<StateObject, Client>, Client is a custom client class
        {
            Send(data, stObj, _socket);
        }
    }
```

Here is the StateObject class:

```
public class StateObject 
{    
    public Socket Server;
    public const int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;
    public byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
}
```

Maybe calling Send() method too many times? Do I have to use "ManualResetEvent" delegate to block or to do something else? I really dont know what to do.

Comment: Please show the code that creates M.StateObject.data.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't have even tried calling Send again before the corresponding callback has fired... if you have other code to send, you should (in particular) *probably* be merging packets to avoid fragmentation... but that shouldn't affect *receive*. What **exactly** does the error say? Your current phrase ("an error of BeginReceive method of Size (3rd parameter)") is rather unclear. What is the size of `data` / `stateObj.data` ? in particular, how is it in relation to `M.StateObject.BUFFSER_SIZE`?

Comment: On the page you linked to I see this exceptionmessage: `size is greater than the length of buffer minus the value of the offset parameter`. Could that be the issue?

Comment: @Silvermind that was pretty much what I was thinking; since the offset is 0, we must conclude that `M.StateObject.BUFFER_SIZE` is greater than `data.Length`.

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah, I see what you mean, but my typing is not so fast on my phone, so you beat me to it :)

Comment: Marc, you point is: Each BegindReceive should (or must) have a callBack (from the other side) Is that what you are talking about?  But what in case if I dont need any call back? This is as you can see "A new client logging in", so I have to do some multiple work to satisfy needs ( you can see which one in the ClientLogging() method). So in this particular case I have to Send only to clients. Or am I wrong? Maybe my logic is wrong... correct me if so please.

Comment: the callback isn't from "the other side" - it is from your side, saying "I sent this" (at least as far as getting it out of .NET and accepted into the NIC buffer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `M.StateObject.BUFFER_SIZE` with `stateObj.data.Length`, somehow `data` is smaller than `BUFFER_SIZE`.

Also I see you put out the data in to an array but don't do anything with it. I would reccomend changing this

```
byte[] data = stateObj.data;
int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
client.BeginReceive(data, 0, M.StateObject.BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData), stateObj);
```

to this

```
int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
client.BeginReceive(stateObj.data, 0, stateObj.data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData), stateObj);
```

and see if that fixes your error.

---

Also I noticed that Your BeginSend is passing in the state object blob. Is the array you used to send data `stateObj.data` too? And if so, are multiple calls to BeginSend using new `stateObj` objects? If they are all sharing the same state object you could have the next send reading the same time as the current receive is writing.

Comment: Damn, how I didnt see that flaw. Big thx mate. Maybe I need some rest, its too much for today.

Comment: As you can see I have a Dictionary collection of all clients. So when new user logs in, I have to pass the list of all clients to this new client, and all the clients has to get this new client too. I dont know how I can do better then this. If you will take a closer look into the code above, you will see what code does. Dont bother with unknown methods, those are only to set the length of the array (in 1st 4 bytes, which are used in client`s side in BeginReceive method.

Comment: I think the way you are doing it is fine, it is just somewhere other than your constructor a method is doing a `stateObj.data = newSmallerArray` and data is no longer the same size a `BUFFER_SIZE`

Comment: However instead of hardcoding the buffer to 2048 you should use [Socket.ReceiveBufferSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivebuffersize.aspx) to size the array for best performance. Also you may want a second array to use [Socket.SendBufferSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.sendbuffersize.aspx) for the sending side instead of having the same array be shared between the sender and the receiver (or if you still want them shared use `Math.Max(this.Server.SendBufferSize, this.Server.ReceiveBufferSize)` for the array size)